# PHP Multiclient socket connection (listening)

Tags: javascript, php, json, sockets

I am looking for some kind of multi client permanent connection which would work as follows.

2 - 3 clients login into website and whenever someone do somethink p.e type in chat or edit an article the other sides will get notification. I have succesfuly finished two side chat according to tutorial, but iam looking for more general solution.

Basically I would like to see any tutorial for multi client socket connection and how to handle it.

Principle in words

1. One side submits form
2. The server side is triggered and prepare a JSON message
3. Server sends to listening client a JSON message

Is it possible? Unfortunately I am not familiar how to handle this server messages so I would welcome any kind of notification push handler. I know how to handle JSON in javascript but how to recieve it?

Comment: Do you have a hard requirement for PHP? I would probably pick NodeJS for this kind of platform.

Comment: I am open to any solutions, cause iam currently developing a logistic system for our company so I have a unlimited access to editing.

Comment: Then I recommend http://socket.io/get-started/chat/